# retrieving selected documents in couchdb

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-python

For example I have documents in couchdb which have the following Ids (1,2,3,4,...,n) and I want just to retrieve e.g. three Ids (2,4,7).

Do I have to query each of them or can I pass anyhow an array with the ids ([2,4,7]) to the view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all the documents with a given list of IDs by making a `POST` request to the `_all_docs` endpoint of your database. The request body is a JSON document with a single field called `keys`, which contains an array of document IDs. If you want the full documents (and not just their IDs and revisions), you also have to supply `include_docs=true` as a query argument. Here is an example with curl:

```
curl https://example.com/db/_all_docs?include_docs=true -X POST -d '
{ "keys": ["2", "4", "7"] }'
```